# Change in pickle file for same object

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I'm pickling an object, then do things to it, then pickle it again, and check it the object is still the same. Maybe not the best way to ensure equality, but a very strict and simple one.

However, I get unexpected difference in the pickle file on some machines running python2.7.
I used [pickletools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickletools.html) to analyze the resulting files.

The difference is additional [PUT codes](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/087cdbf49e80/Lib/pickletools.py#l1782), though these registers are never accessed. When are PUT statements generated, and why are they generated differently when calling pickle twice on the same object?

Comment: any difference in the machines?

Comment: It's slightly different configurations of Travis CI with the same python versions but different builds (ubuntu vs conda). The order of all fields etc is exactly the same, only one of the files has additional PUT commands that are not used. I think I'm using joblib.hash for now, but I still don't understand what's happening here.

Comment: I was wrong about order... deleted.. the docs for pickletools mentions optimizing a pickle file by eliminating unused `PUT` opcodes, so maybe some versions of the pickle library do this automatically

Comment: It's the same minor version of Python, though. I'm not using the latest protocol, maybe that would have fixed it?